# Predicting next event

Tags: machine-learning, weka, prediction

I have a set of data, which has 3 possible events. There are 24 features that effect which of the three events will happen. 
I have training data with all the 24 features and which events happened.

What I want to do is using this data predict which of the three events will happen next, given all the 24 feature values are known.

Could you suggest some machine learning algorithm that I should use to solve this problem

Comment: Does the previous event affect the probability of the next event or is it only dependent on the features?

Comment: @AlexanderBauer yes the previous event effect the probability of next event.

Comment: Are all events equally likely to happen? Or is one of them very rare? How much training data do you have?

Comment: @AlexanderBauer So data is about user responding to a question. Possible events is - yes / no / no response. Likely hood of yes (20%) No(5%)  No response (75%) . For each user I have about 1 month data , about 200 event that already happened. 
Use case is to send a question to the user only if probability of him saying yes is high. So I want to predict this probability.

Comment: ok, and are those 24 features characterizing the user or the questions?

Comment: @AlexanderBauer those 24 features describe both - e.g.: question type, question time, time to respond the question, when did user get the the question, what was his response to the last questions, how many questions he answered in last 24 hours , why did said no to previous question etc.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical classification problem in supervised learning.  However, you haven't given us enough information to suggest a particular algorithm.

We would need statistics about the "shape" of your data: relative clustering and range, correlations among the features, etc.  The critical points so far are that you have few classes (3) and many more features than classes.  What have you considered so far?  Backing up a little, what unsupervised classification algorithms have you researched well enough to use?

My personal approach is to hit such a generic problem with Naive Bayes or multi-class SVM, and use the resulting classification parameters as input for feature reduction.  I might also try a CNN with one hidden layer (or none, just a single FC connection) and then examine the weights to eliminate extraneous features.

Given the large dimensionality, you might also try hitting it with k-means clustering to see whether the classification is already cohesive in 24-D space.  Try k=6; in most runs, this will give you 3 good clusters and 3 tiny outliers.

Does that get you moving toward a solution?